# If my database column has a lot of null values, why shouldn't I use an index on it?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I read an article on tutorials point that says the following:

> Indexes should not be used on columns that contain a high number of NULL values.

It doesn't say for what reason though.

Here's an example I thought of. Let's say I have a table called `girls` and on one of the columns is whether they have a boyfriend or not. Let's say that if they have a boyfriend the value is simply `yes` and if they don't it would just have a value of `NULL`.

Could it be that I wouldn't want to put an index on the has_boyfriend column because I could easily search for either/or type with `SELECT * FROM girls WHERE has_boyfriend IS NULL` or `SELECT * FROM girls WHERE has_boyfriend IS NOT NULL`, thus not necessarily requiring an index because of the simplicity?  It's a contrived example but it's what I thought of.

Comment: A bit outside the scope of the question, but any particular reason why in your example you wouldn't use a `boolean` type and `true`/`false` for the response, especially considering it's a question only (usually) answerable by Yes or No? Can't imagine very many scenarios where `NULL` would be totally appropriate for this data point.

Comment: Hey @esqew, I just couldn't think of an example aside from the above one. That's what I ended up with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indexes on columns with lots of `NULL` values can be useful, particularly if your query is looking at the values that are populated.

For your example, though, you have a different issue.  In general, indexes on binary columns are not useful.  The purpose of indexes is to reduce the number of data pages that need to be read.  In general, binary columns are going to have records with both values on any given data page.

There are two exceptions, but the second doesn't apply to Postgres.  The first is if one of the values is so rare that the values occur on few data pages.  Then an index can be helpful to find them.

The second is for a clustered index.  Because Postgres does not support them, that exception is not relevant.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I think too.